# Plotting FFT fails due to vectors not having the same length

Tags: matlab, plot, fft, spectral-density

I have a csv data of time(1st column) and current amplitude(2nd column). I want to plot FFT of the current. This is actually simulation data over 30ns and data step was 1ps. I can plot the current vs Time in MATLAB. But while doing FFT function, It is not plotting at all as it says

> ```
> Error using plot
> Vectors must be the same length.
>
> Error in FFT_Ideal_current_maxstep_1ps (line 25).
> plot(f,Y)
> ```

Can anyone help me? I have attached the MATLAB code and the [CSV](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/avqi46a9ou0xykx/AACHsfuQAugusniowDFmPPZwa?dl=0) file as well.

I also want to plot the power spectral density. It would be nice if anyone can help. I want to get the FFT and psd over 2GHz or more frequency spectrum range

MATLAB code1:

```
% open data file
fid = fopen('current_maxstep_1ps.csv');

% Read data in from csv file
readData = textscan(fid,'%f %f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');

% Extract data from readData
t = readData{1,1}(:,1);
x = readData{1,2}(:,1);

N = length(x);
ts = 0.000000000001;
Fs = 1/ts;
tmax = (N-1)*ts;
tm = 0:ts:tmax;
f = 0:Fs/(N-1):Fs/2;
y = fftshift(fft(x));
Y = abs(y);
plot(f,Y)
```

Also there is another MATLAB code I tried which plots (here is the picture: [FFT picture of code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adT28.png)) but showing in time domain and I want frequency spectrum like spikes of apmlitudes along the frequency spectrum.

MATLAB Code2:

```
% open data file
fid = fopen('Ideal_current_maxstep_1ps.csv');

% Read data in from csv file
readData = textscan(fid,'%f %f','Headerlines',1,'Delimiter',',');

% Extract data from readData
xData = readData{1,1}(:,1);
yData = readData{1,2}(:,1);

Ts = 1e-12;
Fs = 1/Ts;
%Fs = 1000;
%Ts = 1/Fs;

X = fft(yData);
plot(xData, abs(X))
```

Comment: What is unusual?

Comment: You should look at using `csvread` to make your life easier reading in the data! You need to be specific about what you think "looks unusual", we can't help with vague problems.

Comment: Sorry "unusual" comment. The above code here somehow is not running right now it says "Error plotting plot(f,Y)"

Comment: @aguntuk Please always copy the whole error message (as I did it now for you) or at least the mentioned error not only where the error occurs.

Comment: @m7913d Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aguntuk I rollbacked your changes, because they hide your initial problem. The goal of SO is to provide a resource of Q&A for others with the same problem. Feel free to ask a new question when needed and link to your previous question if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the length of `f` and `Y` are not the same. You can check it using `length(f)` and `length(Y)`. The reason is that `fft` also calculates the negative frequencies. Therefore, you should define `f` as follows:

```
f = -Fs/2:Fs/(N-1):Fs/2;
```

*Note* that the fft is conjugate symmetric, because the input data is real.

You can *limit the plotted frequency* range using the `xlim` command as follows:

```
xlim([0 3*10^9]) % limit x range between 0Hz and 3GHz
```

[image]

Comment: @m7913d, but I cannot use `length(f)` or `length(Y)` to define `N` as f is defined later based on `N` and `Fs`.

Comment: In my case it says length of `f` and `y` are same which is 30334, I checked now.

Comment: Are they `30334` in your original code? What is the value of `N`? Did you got a different error message? Your definition of `N` is ok. Just change the definition of `f` as in my answer.

Comment: The error message is gone and I tried your and I tried your code for defining `f` it worked symmetrically but I want the frequency spectrum more around 2GHz or mre than 2GHz like 2.5 or 3GHz. As my simulated circuit should work in 2GHz so I want to know the frequency spectrum around that. How to move the spectrum for that high frequency? I posted the result as new answer to attach the figure. Do you have any idea how to plot it for higher frequency range. I know the sampling frequency should be higher as well but no idea how to define that for my existing data.

Comment: Thanks it worked but there is a spike at 2GHz in your plot, but in my plot, it's almost flat. <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXrL7.png" width="100" height="100">

Comment: Maybe, you are using different data? I used the link you provided.

Comment: no, I checked it...it's same... did ou use same code? like defining `Ts` or `Fs` or any other definition?

Comment: I just copy paste your code and change/add the two lines from my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a mistake. defining  `Ts`. now it looks like you. Do you know how to do PSD? power spectral density. Again thank you very much.

Comment: Is the PSD not just the square of the above result due to the real input? See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density).

Comment: ok..thanks. I will get back to you again whether I am successful or not. Thank you again for the effort and help.

Comment: I have a bit question as I am told my supervisor to normalize the FFT which is needed. If I normalize it I get almost flat (not in a sense full flat) curve (FYI, I also deleted the DC component by removing average value of the signal). To preserve my signal energy (as per Pareseval's theorem)  the FFT needs to be normalized by  `1/sqrt(N)`. it is written in the following [link](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/162846-amplitude-of-signal-after-fft-operation?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com). Inn that case I don't get any peak at my operation frequency 2GHz. Any idea?

Comment: Does this correspond with your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664216/fft-and-psd-of-current-signal-and-analysis)?