# FFT and PSD of current signal and analysis

Tags: fft, spectral-density

I have a current signal which I obtained from cadence simulation over 30ns time but my current actually varies (which I call active region) over certain period. I extracted the data of current signal over 1ps fixed step and plotted the current. Then to analyze frequency spectrum and powers spectral density I used FFT and PSD in MATLAB. But I am confused about what this analyse mean and how can  realize it.

The operation frequency of my circuit is 2GHz. So my goal is to see the frequency spectrum and power at this operation frequency. Now so far I understood I need to normalize the signal while doing FFT in MATLAB. I did it. If my current signal is `x`, I did FFT using the equation `FFT_x = abs(fft(x)/sqrt(N))` where I `N = length(x)`, e.g., length of my current signal. But I do not get any peak at my operation frequency (2 GHz) and not even in any other frequency also. The FFT is like below (NB: I shifted the plot to one sided for my analysis of my operation frequency).

[image: FFT_normalized]

But if I don't normalize I get peak at my operation frequency (2 GHz) where I used `FFT_x = fftshift(fft(x));` The plot is given below:

[image: FFT_not_normalized]

Now the later plot is not normalized but I have something to realize my goal. But I cannot say it as my FFT as I read in various forums that I need to normalize the signal. While normalizing it the spectrum is almost flat. How can I use it for my analysis.

Also my PSD is similar like the plot of normalizing FFT except the amplitude value is different if I do it over normalizing FFT as `psd = abs(fft(x).^2);`

Do you have any idea how do I do the analysis here. Did I do any mistake?

Also it would be nice if I could get some good reference for FFT and PSD for my case.

After solving the above problem. I have two concern. In many papers or references I have read that windowing is needed to do FFT. Is it needed? What is the importance of this? if so, How can I do that?

Another one is - how to show the Perseval's theorem? I mean the power before FFT and the power after FFT is same as per Perseval's theorem. How can I code it in MATLAB?

Comment: Is there anyone to help me out?

Comment: Are you sure the only difference between the two graphs is a division by `sqrt(N)` of fft(x)? Also, I think you should normalise with `N` not `sqrt(N)`. It should just scale your graph as a whole.

Comment: @m7913d thanks. my initial problem is solved now. After 3 days, I found out that I had coding problem as I didn't shift the center frequency. It's good question about normalizing by `sqrt(N)`. I also thought that normalizing by `N` is the way. But in this [link](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/162846-amplitude-of-signal-after-fft-operation?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), one guy told that normalizing by `sqrt(N)` is the right approach. What is your opinion about that?

Comment: I lso have two more concerns, which I edited in the main question. In many papers or references I have read that windowing is needed to do FFT. Is it needed? What is the importance of this? if so, How can I do that?

Another one is - how to show the Perseval's theorem? I mean the power before FFT and the power after FFT is same as per Perseval's theorem. How can I code it in MATLAB?

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple question at once. The goal of SO it to create Q&A which are useful for later reference. See [ask]. Consider creating an answer for your original question and posting other questions as a new one.

Comment: 1) Scaling factor: as described in your link, it depends on what you want. 2) windowing: useful if signal is not periodic, i.e. begin and end or not the same, to avoid end effects.

Comment: so far in some other ref also it is said to normalize by `sqrt(N)`. I am confused now. When `N` and `sqrt(N)` are used and what purpose?

Comment: I suggest you to ask a separate question about it including the references you found.

Comment: Thanks I added a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834006/normalizing-fft-by-n-or-sqrtn-in-matlab) for the normalization issue. I have another issue that you answered about FFT. I asked that in [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776612/using-ifft-to-get-original-signal-and-parsevals-theorem)